# SQL Like statement to match with values from an array

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-like

I am getting color values in an array. I got the following statement from a different thread.

```
strArray = Split("red, blue, orange, blue",",")
For i = 0 to Ubound(strArray)
Execute("n" & (i+1) & " = Trim(strArray(" & i & "))")
Next
```

This assigns colors values in array to n1,n2,n3,n4. I want to search DB with n values with LIKE statement as given below. The problem is that if there are values of n1,n2,n3,n4 available then sql statement works. But if there are two or three n values, then the LIKE does not find anything. How to match LIKE with number of n values in this sql statement.

Values are assigned in above statement as n1=red, n2=blue, n3=orange and so on.
I am using MS SQL 2005 database.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column LIKE '%n1%' OR column LIKE '%n2%' OR column LIKE '%n3%' OR column LIKE '%n4%'
```

I can do it by using if and elseif statement by counting array, but is there any better way. 
ColorN=Ubound(strArray) + 1

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: I don't think you are going to get a useful answer to your question since you don't indicate what database you are using (previous comment), don't indicate what language the array-setting logic is in, and don't explain the format of "Column" in "table".  Also, I don't understand how your LIKE search criteria will ever work since it searches for the characters "n1" rather than the color "red", for example.  Please consider editing your question to give more information.

Comment: I have edited the question with database name.